# Private key to PEM

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, wireshark, decryption

I'm new to security and I'm trying to decode some SSL encrypted communication between my machine and server. I managed to obtain private and public keys 
as far as I understand private key is this one:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 

[private key content]

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

However, Wireshark requires key to be in `.pem` format to decode communication, can I somehow convert my keys to this format?  If no, then how application which uses those packages decodes them?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Have you tried to google it? here's one of the answers from googling `ppk to pem`. http://www.linuxhelp.in/2012/04/creating-pem-key-from-ppk-key.html

Answer (score 11):

The ".PEM format" does not really exist as a standard. This is more "whatever OpenSSL does".

PEM comes from an old failed standard for [Privacy Enhanced Mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-enhanced_Electronic_Mail) (that's what the acronym means). These days, "PEM" really means: some text that looks like:

```
-----BEGIN XXX-----
[some Base64 stuff here]
-----END XXX-----
```

I.e. a header line that starts with `-----` and contains the designation of the type of data (e.g. "RSA PRIVATE KEY"); a similar trailer line; and between these two lines, a binary object encoded in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

For RSA private keys, you will encounter mostly two types of PEM-encoded formats. When the header contains "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" then this is a RSA private key in the format described by [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.1.2). When the header says "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY" (without the "RSA") then it uses [PKCS#8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208), a wrapper format that includes the designation of the key type ("RSA") and the private key itself.

In your case, if you see something that looks like PEM and begins with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` then it *is* PEM; just put that in a text file, save it under some name (say "serverkey.pem") and configure Wireshark to use that file as server key. This is described in the [Wireshark documentation](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL).

Mind some details, though:

- Wireshark will probably not be able to read the file if it is encoded in UTF-16 (what Windows somewhat improperly calls "Unicode"). In UTF-16, each *character* is encoded over two bytes (or four bytes for some characters like [Pahawh Hmong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pahawh_Hmong)). If you are using Windows' notepad, upon saving the file, choose the "ANSI" or "UTF-8" encoding.
- Knowing the server's private key is not enough to decrypt the data if the client and server use a "DHE" or "ECDHE" cipher suite. If the client and server agree to use such a cipher suite and you still want to intercept the data, then you must make an *active* attack (a [Man-in-the-Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)) in which you impersonate the server when talking to the client, and the client when talking to the server. This is a lot more work and Wireshark won't help you much there.

Comment: Thank you for the insight how it all works. I looked around and found out that communication indeed uses DHE. However I've learned much, so it's no biggie! :)

Comment: Note Wireshark can't read encrypted PEM keys (PKCS1 `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` with `Proc-type` and `DEK-info` headers or PKCS8 `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY`); you can decrypt with `openssl rsa`, `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt`, or `openssl pkey` *without* `-$cipher`. If you have PKCS12 (not PEM, no header line, always encrypted) openssl *can* convert that, but Wireshark can use it directly given the password. If it still doesn't decrypt, turning on and looking at log can help; that's (now) in the GUI Edit/Preferences/Protocols/SSL and you needn't fiddle config files.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a file with a ".pem" extension and try using it.

According to this [page](http://how2ssl.com/articles/working_with_pem_files/), the the private key is stored in a PEM file like you described:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 

[code in whatever format it may be]

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```